apt-get upgrade with broken libgl1:i386 libgl1 libglvnd0 ibglx0:i386 libglx0
SO: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Everything was working! This week it broke some packages when running sudo apt-get upgrade.
 libgl1 : Depende: libglx0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
          Quebra: libgl1:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
 libgl1:i386 : Depende: libglx0:i386 (= 1.4.0-1) mas 1.7.0-2101~22.04 está instalado
               Quebra: libgl1 (!= 1.4.0-1) mas 1.7.0-2101~22.04 está instalado
 libglvnd0 : Quebra: libglvnd0:i386 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
 libglvnd0:i386 : Quebra: libglvnd0 (!= 1.4.0-1) mas 1.7.0-2101~22.04 está instalado
 libglx-dev : Depende: libglx0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
 libglx0 : Depende: libglvnd0 (= 1.4.0-1) mas 1.7.0-2101~22.04 está instalado
           Quebra: libglx0:i386 (!= 1.4.0-1) mas 1.7.0-2101~22.04 está instalado
 libglx0:i386 : Depende: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
                Quebra: libglx0 (!= 1.7.0-2101~22.04) mas 1.4.0-1 está instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente 'apt --fix-broken install' sem nenhum pacote (ou especifique uma solução).

Output for sudo apt --fix-broken install and sudo apt-get install -f:
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto        
Corrigindo dependências... Pronto
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libvulkan1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libxcb-keysyms1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
Utilize 'sudo apt autoremove' para os remover.
Os pacotes adicionais seguintes serão instalados:
  libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0
3 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 8 não atualizados.
17 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
É preciso baixar 0 B/227 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] s
(Lendo banco de dados ... 205166 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb ...
A descompactar libglx0:amd64 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 a tentar sobreescrever '/usr/share/doc/libglx0/changelog.Debian.gz' partilhado, que é diferente de outras instâncias do pacote libglx0:amd64
A preparar para desempacotar .../libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
A descompactar libgl1:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 a tentar sobreescrever '/usr/share/doc/libgl1/changelog.Debian.gz' partilhado, que é diferente de outras instâncias do pacote libgl1:i386
A preparar para desempacotar .../libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
A descompactar libglvnd0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 a tentar sobreescrever '/usr/share/doc/libglvnd0/changelog.Debian.gz' partilhado, que é diferente de outras instâncias do paco
te libglvnd0:i386
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I have already removed APT LIST and installed it again, the error still persists.
Maybe I can clean these packages? Uninstall?
Any suggestion?

Did you attempt to run sudo apt --fix-broken install like the eerror messsge says?

Add all output as edits to your question please.  Comments do not properly display it in any way it can be easily processed.

Ready!! Done...

Please add also sudo apt update to your question. I think some packages are from a ppa.
